# Outlook Antwort Vs RE

Tags: email, outlook

My Client based in Germany is using an email system which prefixes their email reply subjects with **Antwort:** rather than the Microsoft Outlook standard **RE:** or **AW:** (in Germany).

is there a way to get Outlook to Recognize **Antwort:** as the equivalent of **RE:** in the subject line so I don't end up with email subjects like:

RE: Antwort: RE: Antwort: RE: The Important Project

Answer (score 0):

I searched a bit and found this one: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/use-re-and-fw-instead-of-localized-subject-prefix

Unfortunately I'm not sure if the options are just for changing the outgoing mails, but it's worth to try. ;)